# How to I upload to wordpress media library

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom php form that upload images to a folder on my website. Currently that folder is outside the wp-content folder.
I want the content of the folder to be automatically uploaded to Google drive. There are plenty of plugins or a zapier solution to do that if the folder is in the wp media folder.

My question is...Can I just upload the images directly to the wp media folder or do I need to use a special wp method/function/api call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload media directly to the media library.  Given your situation `media_handle_upload()` is probably the most logical way.  Can read its documentation here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/media_handle_upload/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/60807/180725

Once you upload the media (to where you want, ftp, dropbox, s3 etc) you will need to register it with Wordpress.

```
$file_name = 'Some Name';
$file_path = '/path/to/uploads/2012/08/04/newfile.jpg';
$file_url = 'http://url/to/uploads/2012/08/04/newfile.jpg';
$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($file, null);
$attachment = array(
    'guid'           => $file_url,
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title'     => $file_name,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_date'      => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $file_path);
$attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $file_path);
wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a solution to upload files to wordpress Mediathek / Library from an external Source/URL, I recommend the following code:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
$filename = basename($image_url);
if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))
    $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
else
    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
$attachment = array(
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'inherit'
);
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_ID );
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

set_post_thumbnail( $post_ID, $attach_id );
```

Original post here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/169598